# Algorithm help, horrible at math

Tags: algorithm

I am messing around with some Javascript game development, trying to create a simple Framework for drawing a playing field (for a sports game).

I am horrible at math and really need help with this algorithm.

Say I have these variables:

```
GAME_WIDTH = 1024;  
FIELD_LENGTH = 170;  
PLAYER_SPEED = 4.72;  
update_duration = 30;
```

The first 3 in caps are variable, meaning they can be set by the user.  The last is essentially how often my "update" code is called in 1 second.

GAME_WIDTH is pixels, FIELD_LENGTH is meters, PLAYER_SPEED is how many seconds a player can cover 40 meters.

What I want to do, is take those 4 variables and translate that into how many pixels a player can move in 1 "update".  I have never really done any Game Development and I never payed attention to Geometry or Trigonometry in school so I am completely at a loss here.
Can anyone help?

**EDIT**
This is a 2D top-down game so this algorithm is only dealing with X (right-to-left) coordinates.

Comment: What is the connection between `GAME_WIDTH` and `FIELD_LENGTH`?

Comment: What's the connection between meters and pixels? That scale factor seems to be missing. Also, you speak of "width" and "length", but there's no "height" or "depth" or "breadth" or any other suitably paired extent. That's confusing.

Comment: using this `(stadium.PITCH_WIDTH / (stadium.pitch_length / 40)) / this.speed / msDuration` I come up with roughly 1.70~ which seems very, very slow when the players are actually moving....so I think I did something wrong.

Comment: GAME_WIDTH == FIELD_LENGTH.  One is the actual pixel dimensions on the screen, the other is how many meters the field is from end to end.   @Kerrek SB: I don't need Height or Depth or Breadth.  It is a 2D topdown game.  We are speaking completely about X coordinates (right-to-left) for this.

Comment: @James: That information would have been useful as part of the question! :-)

Comment: David's answer appears to be correct. I didn't check the math, but assuming he didn't make a mistake on that, his logic is accurate. HOWEVER... I don't recommend using it in your code. Rather think in terms of "How many pixels per second does the player move" I would use two loops: one for logic, and one for graphics. The logic would update as often as it feels necessary, and the graphics would simply render where all the players and stuff is. All the calculations would be done in meters and seconds, and just get rendered as they get rendered. Problem solved.

Comment: @glowcoder : That is actually what is occurring.  My "update" method is the one doing this math and it is basically saying "this.x = ALGORITHM", but the "draw" method is what is actually drawing things to the screen.  So unless I misunderstand what you are saying, essentially that's what I'm doing.

Comment: @James you may be doing that, but what unit is `this.x` in? Is it in meters? Or pixels. Meters is good. Pixels, not so good. Also, having your game-update logic tied down to your graphics logic is another potential problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to embrace the fine art of "Units Conversion".
http://oakroadsystems.com/math/convert.htm

For example, 12 inches = 1 foot. So you can convert inches to feet like so:

48 inches * (1 foot / 12 inches) = 4 feet. The "inches" cancel out, leaving just feet.

So the answer we want is pixels per update. (Is update_duration in milliseconds? assuming so...)

```
(40 meters / 4.72 seconds) 
 * (1024 pixels / 170 meters) 
 * (1 second / 1000 ms) 
 * (30 ms / 1 update) = 1.53140578 pixels / update
```

or if the 30 is updates/second, same idea:

```
  (40 meters / 4.72 seconds) 
   * (1024 pixels / 170 meters) 
   * (1 second / 30 updates = 1.70156198 pixels / update
```

(I may have misinterpreted the meaning of your constants... but that's the technique. The concept is that each of those fractions, a / b, is equivalent to "1".

This looks better when you write it in full classroom fraction style, all the canceling becomes chalkboard-perfect. Very useful technique to embrace.

Comment: That is relatively close to what I came up with, but the problem with that is at that "speed" it takes that player approximately 30 seconds to travel "170 meters" but at a speed of 40 meters in 4.72 seconds it should take around 20 seconds approximately (very fuzzy math there, but still a big difference)

Comment: It's not 30ms per update, but 30 updates per second, I believe.

Comment: I treated your duration as 30 ms, not 30 updates/second, which is why our answers are different, but that's the math and it gives the answer! Have to futz something if you want it more pixels / update. :)

Comment: I think this gives me a good starting point at least.  I don't mind fuzzing the numbers a bit here.

Answer (score 2):

Just multiply everything up so that the correct units come out:

```
 1024 px      40 m          1 s               px
 -------  x  ------  x  ----------  =  1.70 ------
  170 m      4.72 s     30 updates          update
```

(If you want to impress your friends at the next cocktail party, say you solved it by "dimensional analysis" :-) .)

You probably don't want to work with the pixel/update ratio directly. Rather, you want to keep track of the total number of pixels that have been traversed after a certain time and render those. The point is that you cannot make sense of fractional pixel counts, so you can only advance by either one or two pixels per update, but how do you know which one? Rather, you could say "now it's the 10th update, so I need to be at pixel 17."

Answer (score 1):

So, what you want is how many pixels there are to the meter...

That's Pixels/Meters. In other words, you take the number of pixels and divide it by the number of meters, and you get the number of pixels per meter;

```
1024 pixels/ 170 meters = about 6 pixels / meter.
```

If someone can run 40 meters in 4.72 seconds. You need to know how many meters they can run per second. That's meters/second.

Again take the number of meters and divide it by seconds and you get meters/second:

```
40 meters/ 4.72 seconds = about 8.5 meters / second.
```

Now, you want to know how many pixels that person can move in a second. We have:

```
6 pixels/meter  and 8.5 meters/seconds
```

Look at the units:

```
  pixels/meter    meters/seconds
```

Let's say we multiply them:

```
 pixels * meters / meters * seconds
```

Meters are on the bottom and top, so let's eliminate them and get pixels / seconds. Let's do that:

```
6 pixels/meter * 8.5 meters/seconds = 51 pixels / second
```

That's pretty much the secret: You look at the units and see how you can manipulate them.

BTW,  you know that the number of pixels will change depending upon the direction the player moves. For example, this only works if the player is moving across or vertically. If the player is moving at an angle, you have to figure out the actual length using the ol' [pythagorean theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem).

Comment: Thanks for the note about good ole Pythagorous...I think it might actually be time to pull out my old math books from high school if I really want to work this stuff out properly.
:)